Check if clang::Expr evaluates to NULL using oclint
I`m currently making a set of custom OCLint rules for my university and I need to catch statements like:
char *str = strdup("Hello, world!");
if (str == NULL) {   // That`s what i`m interested in
    ...
}

So how do I check if an Expr is NULL? I know there is a method Expr::isNullPointerConstant(ASTContext &Ctx, NullPointerConstantValueDependence NPC), but I don't know how to get ASTContext  from my oclint::AbstractASTVisitorRule. There are no mentions of anything like that in documentation (or that`s just me, idk \_(0_0)_/)
How do I do that?

What is the problem with the statements you show? Why do you need to be able to "catch" them using static code analysis? Is the goal to check if str is actually a null pointer or not? It's not possible to do run-time checking using a static code analyzer.

@Someprogrammerdude these statements are OK. I have a rule that catches comparisons with string literals (ex. str == "Hello"). But this rule also catches str == NULL. So I need to prevent it from happening.

I figured out how to get ASTContext: this->_carrier->getASTContext() where this is AbstractASTVisitorRule

Please [edit] your question to include such details.

That`s how I did it and it works I guess.
namespace oclint {
    class StringCompareRule : public oclint::AbstractASTVisitorRule<StringCompareRule>
    {

    // ...

        bool IsNull(clang::Expr *expr)
        {
            return expr->isNullPointerConstant(*this->_carrier->getASTContext(), clang::Expr::NPC_ValueDependentIsNotNull);
        }

    // ...
}



As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
